# Is there a quick and intuitive way to derive $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Is there a quick and intuitive way to derive the following finite sum for integer $n\geq 3$?

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$$

Please, do not suggest proofs by induction, since these require prior knowledge of the result, which makes the derivation circular. I'm curious to see a way to quickly determine what the result is in the first place.

How I come up with the equality:

Define

$$s_n=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}$$

evaluate the first few terms by hand

$$s_3=\frac{1}{6}~,~s_4=\frac{1}{4}~,~s_5=\frac{3}{10}~,~s_6=\frac{1}{3}~,~s_7=\frac{5}{14}~,~s_8=\frac{3}{8}~,~s_9=\frac{7}{18}$$

take an ansatz for what the result possibly might look like

$$S_n=\frac{a_{-3}}{n^3}+\frac{a_{-2}}{n^2}+\frac{a_{-1}}{n}+a_0+a_1 n+a_2 n^2+ a_3 n^3$$

evaluate this ansatz for the same range of explicit $n$ values as above and solve the resulting system of linear equations for the $a_i$. This directly gives:

$$a_{-3}=a_{-2}=a_1=a_2=a_3=0~,~a_{-1}=-1~,~a_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Finally, with the result known, do usual proof by induction.

Comment: First establish that you know "a way" before asking for  "a quick and intuitive way" to solve it.  So please include in your post the method you used to solve the problem.  Then ask others if there is a quicker and more intuitive way.  Unfortunately, with you rep, I'm surprised to be in a position to remind you that we are not here to do your work for you.  So please, contribute to and participate in your process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**
$$
\frac{1}{i(i+1)} = \frac1i-\frac1{i+1}
$$
and telescoping series